# Create unique groups row wise based on logical vector in data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I think there must be a solution on SO for this but I've been searching around solutions with *almost* what I want, but not quite. **Looking for a tidyverse solution, if possible.**

I have a data.frame, say newdf:

```
newdf <- data.frame(inside.city = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

newdf
  inside.city
1        TRUE
2        TRUE
3        TRUE
4       FALSE
5       FALSE
6        TRUE
7       FALSE
8       FALSE
```

Every time someone "leaves the city" (inside.city == FALSE), I want to give their trip a unique group number, so that the resulting data.frame looks like this:

```
  inside.city group
1        TRUE    NA
2        TRUE    NA
3        TRUE    NA
4       FALSE     1
5       FALSE     1
6        TRUE    NA
7       FALSE     2
8       FALSE     2
```

Assume the data are already ordered by the date.

**How can I do this efficiently?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way using `mutate()`. I just transform the column twice to simplify things

```
library(dplyr)
newdf %>% mutate(group=cumsum(!inside.city & lag(inside.city, default=TRUE)), 
                 group=ifelse(inside.city, NA, group))
```

Basically you just increment when you see a FALSE after a TRUE and then set the TRUE values to NA.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick! Can you explain what the `&` means in this context?

Comment: It's the logical "and" operator.

Comment: I have never seen it used to combine TRUEs and FALSEs before.

Comment: It won't work if the first row of inside.city is FALSE.

Comment: @tmfmnk you can just add `default=TRUE` to the `lag()` call.